# How do I disable my dedicated Radeon HD gpu and switch to intel graphics

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, gpu, amdgpu

I'm a complete rookie when it comes to Ubuntu, I am currently trying to disable my Radeon HD 7570M gpu and switch to intel HD 4000 integrated graphics. I don't have any clue how to do this safely, I have tried a method that suggested editing the grub file but that just completely shattered my system to where it couldn't boot (was able to fix after 8 excruciating hours), so I'm very scared to try and fiddle on my own now.

The machine in question is a old EliteBook 8570p, and the gpu is running extremely hot even at normal tasks such as using chrome. I am running Kubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (jammy jellyfish), and as far as I know the card is only compatible with amdgpu drivers on Ubuntu versions past 16.04, so those are the drivers I have installed. I have managed to find a lot of stuff explaining how to do this for NVIDIA gpus, but the ones I've tried before messing everything up didn't work, and as I've already said, I'm not keen to do things at my own discretion now (lol).

One suggested way I've seen a couple times is to uninstall the drivers, would that work? Any other suggestions/methods are welcome, and if any additional information is needed, I will provide it as soon as I can.

Thank you very much for your help and time.

Comment: Disabling means the OS driver is removed. BUT the GPU still may get hot just by being plugged in. If it has a physical issue can you remove it from the machine?

Comment: @David well i actually thought about this before ediitng my post, as i had opened it up and realized it was soldered on hahah - but my thought process is, if i switch to integrated graphics, that might take the load off the gpu completely... this would be so easy to do in windows, just disable the device in the device manager, but i guess ubuntu doesnt offer such a utility either...

Comment: If it has its own fan start by using some compressed air to clean the fan other then that you may need to take it for repair.

Comment: @David appreciate the input but thats not quite the solution im looking for... would uninstalling the drivers work? dont wanna mess something up...

Comment: Wlcome to AskUbuntu. The Notebookcheck site [reviewed](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-HP-EliteBook-8570p-B6Q03EA-ABD-Notebook.82291.0.html) this particular model. He says "It is not possible to turn the discrete GPU off and use an Intel HD 4000 with the BIOS hardware settings." Other models come with discrete GPU have either dynamic and fixed switch in the BIOS menu and [this one doesn't](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Video-Display-and-Touch/HP-Elitebook-8470p-Switchable-Graphics/td-p/5893427).